# Compare local text file with online file

Tags: powershell

I want to compare local text file with online file via PowerShell, the content of two files are the same.

I know I have to use `Compare-Object` cmdlet to compare two files, and I found I could get the content of online file by `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet (https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-download-URL-content-using-Get-Content-in-PowerShell-Script). But it's not working as expected. It just output the file content of the online version.

```bsh
$item1 = cat $path
$item2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL | select -ExpandProperty Content

# No working as expected
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $item1 -DifferenceObject $item2
```

**Updates**

After debugging, I found out that the type of return value is `System.Array` when using `Get-Content` (`cat`), but when using `Invoke-WebRequest` it's `String`.

```
PS C:\> $item1.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS C:\> $item2.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Comment: **"but It's not working as expected"**  What is it doing?  Any output at all?  Any errors?

Comment: @boxdog I have updated the description a little bit

Comment: Your approach will not lead to a satisfactory result. Compare Object really only helps compare the properties of two objects, i.e. does one object have a property that the other object does not have and it checks when both objects have a property of the same name if its value is differs. If you want to see the exact differences between the files you're better of using a tool such as diff or git diff. However, if you only want to know if the files are the same then you can download both and run `Get-FileHash` to compare their checksums. If they're same the files are identical.

Comment: @megamorf That is incorrect. `Compare-Object` is perfectly suitable for comparing 2 arrays of strings to get the differing lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Invoke-WebRequest` returns the content of the requested web page as a single string. Split the string at newlines and you'll be able to compare it to the data from the text file (`Get-Content` produces an array of strings by default).

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $item1 -DifferenceObject ($item2 -split '\r?\n')
```

Comment: you are right, I tried your code, it's not working, update it a little bit, it works now.

```powershell
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $item1 -DifferenceObject ($item2 -split '\r\n')
```

Comment: However, the depends on the endline, need to make this scripts working for "LF" and "CRLF"

Comment: I found the regexp usage in "-split" is a little weird, "(" or ")" can't be used inside'', have to change it to: `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $item1 -DifferenceObject  ($item2 -split '\r?\n')`

Comment: @KevinXiong `(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind assertion. But apparently it doesn't work the way I expected (it seems to ignore the CR characters). Not sure why. Amended my answer.

Comment: I know lookbehind assertion in regexp, but it's not woking in powershell. not sure if it's a bug or by design.

Comment: It usually does work, just not in this case. Like I said, not sure why that is.

Comment: I got it, we actually don't need to use lookbehind assertion in this case, lookbehind assertion is what we need it in the match, we don't need it while processing the string. got stupid when I see you use regexp...